# Law of corresponding states (equation expansion)

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I was reading Cambridge lecture notes on Statistical physics, and I came across this equation where they used some technique of expansion which honestly I couldn't understand how. So my question is how they found the last equation from the second one. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you replace the values on $T$ as they suggest and do the taylor expansion in terms of epsilon you get the series $1- \epsilon^2 /16 - 3 \epsilon^4 /32 + ...$

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you so much!